# Exception in page with Radedit

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a problem in my web-app. Sometimes user click an element this exception throws.
I tried to reproduce user's actions, but it didn't appear.

```
Error:

Message: Input string was not in a correct format. 

Original URL: /jobs/edit.aspx/en 

on us.rightrjo.com:80 

User address: 10.0.20.54 

UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; Touch; MDDCJS) 

Stack trace: 

Error  source: mscorlib 

Inner Exception:  

Error  stack trace:    at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputImage.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputImage.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

I even cant know which action really throws this.

Best regards, Dmitry.

Comment: error is clear from the name that one of your `input string is not in correct format`..means ex : means in the error line you are passing `integer` as a `string`,,something like that,,show me your code where you getting problem..

Comment: thats the problem...the only informtion I got is this copypaste from client, and his actiont (he clicked on radedit control). I know what this exception does, but I need to understand where it can be thrown.

Comment: without any code how i can tell you that where is the problem..In stack trace you will get line number as well.

Comment: I think that exception thrown when System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain is called. But where it was called I can't find.